# Print selected nodes in General Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

General trees in Java are those that don't have any limit on the number of children it can have. Now let's I select the only few nodes of the tree. How do I print the tree structure for selected nodes only? Let's say I select a,i and b. The output should be like

```
Input:
a            b            c
e   f   g 
h i g

Output:

a  b
i
```

Here is how the code looks like

```
Class Node {
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_node_id")
private Node parentNode;
@OneToMany
private List<Node> subNodes;
}
```

I have many such nodes independent trees and I will get a list of nodes selected. .The nodes could belong to the same

Comment: There are many issues with this question: you don't show any code for the structures so it's impossible to ask advice; it's unclear what the input is supposed to represent as a tree; you don't explain how to identify selected nodes. I suggest you rewrite the question.

Comment: Let me add more details to it